# How to use foreach loops in one foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

How to use two foreach loops in one foreach loop.

```
foreach ($user_package as $package_id)
{
    $package_detail = Package::all()->where('id','=',$package_id->package_id);
}

foreach ($package_detail as $package)
{
    $package_amount = $package->price;
    $package_tagline = $package->tagline;
}
```

Comment: You simply put the foreach inside the other foreach (inside the `{...}`). The above code are running them after each other. You're also overwriting all the variables on each iteration so they will only contain the value from the last iteration. I'm guessing you suppose to use those variables for something?

Comment: Yes @MagnusEriksson is right if you want to get variables outside the foreach then make a one array outside the foreach and put the value in array variable 

try this if you want to get the variables in out side the foreach

Answer (score 3):

You can pluck the id's to an array

```
$userPackageIds = UserPackage::pluck('package_id')->toArray();
```

im assuming your model name is UserPackage.

And retrieve all packages using the ids

```
$package_detail = Package::whereIn('id',$userPackageIds);
```

Your code will be like this

```
$userPackageIds = UserPackage::pluck('package_id')->toArray();
$package_detail = Package::whereIn('id',$userPackageIds);

foreach( $package_detail as $package ){
    $package_amount = $package->price;
    $package_tagline = $package->tagline;
}
```